# How to continue reading a Mongodb cursor?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In this simplified example, I have a query that returns 10 documents.

I would like to return the first half (n = 5) to my client first. If he wants to continue reading, he can submit a request and I return him the next half ( n = 5)

in pyMongo:

`doc = collection.find({'foo': 'bar'}).limit(10)`

A not-so-clever way, IMO, is that I can split the `doc` cursor into two, give my client `doc[:4]` then give him `doc[5:]` upon request.

Is this the best way? Are there any methods that can return the position where I left off, and allow me to come back reading the rest of the documents?

Comment: You could use the .skip() method for small collections. Without providing additional information how you data is stored (Are they sorted, What is the index?), it´s quite hard to propose a optimal method.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason to not to use `pymongo.cursor.Cursor.next` method?

```
try:
    c = collection.find({'foo': 'bar'}).limit(10)

    # Take first five
    for in range(5):
        doc = c.next()

    #If you need more
    for in range(5):
        doc = c.next()

 # If there is no next
 except StopIteration:
     pass
```